# While sending request: Bad Request

Tags: http, go, proxy

I am taking use proxy to use POST method.
GET requests are successful, but there are problems with POST.
As I understand it, the POST request timed out, and therefore an error appears.
This is a proxy problem, or something I don't understand?
Code:

```
func main() {
WowProxy := getProxyFromWeb()
fmt.Println(WowProxy)
client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(WowProxy)}}
req, err := client.PostForm("https://example.com", url.Values{"someKey" : {"SomeValue"}})
if err != nil{
    panic(err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(req) }
```

Error:

```
panic: Post "https://example.com": Bad Request
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image but include it instead as (properly formatted) text.

Comment: Please edit the question to include text, not images. We do not need colors (no one does, actually); for the formatting help, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: As to the essense of the question, "Bad request" is the HTTP status code 400 which mean the server thinks the request is not propely formatted ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)). To know what's wrong with it, you have to refer to the docs describing the HTTP endpoint you're trying to access and compare what's in them with what your code is doing. Your code does not have any _programming_ error but supposedly it just creates the request in a way which does not meet the server's expectations. We cannot help you with this without knowing these expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing, would return a 400 Bad Request error.

[400 Bad Request as per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: In this case a compatible server would respond with the [405 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) — Method not allowed.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the heads up. I'll edit my answer to remove the misinformation.